# Ngnix id retrieve using /id

Tags: nginx

How can I force nginx to retrieve me id using this link http://www.website.com/event-details/46

Instead of http://www.website.com/event-details?id=46

Here is my nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    include snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;

    root /var/www/html/website;

    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name website.com www.website.com

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
```

}

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
location /event-details {
               try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }
    location @rewrite {
               rewrite ^/event-details/(.*)$ /event-details.php?id=$1;
    }
```

It may help someone one day